# How can i load correctly a images in p5.js in a server

Tags: javascript, p5.js

p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path [http://www.adsmedia.pe/demos-publicidad/imagenes/super.png] is correct, hosting the image online, or running a local server.[https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server] p5.js:48242:7

Please somebody could help me with this, I have changed the path to relative and absolutes path and nothing works

Comment: I get a 404 when I visit that URL. Are you sure that's where the image is located?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: function preload() {
 img = loadImage('super.png');
 bg = loadImage('fondo_juego.png');

 iniciobg = loadImage('fondo-inicio.png');
 letrasInicio = loadImage('letras-inicio.png');
 señalSuper = loadImage('super-inicio.png');
 iniciarLetras = loadImage('iniciar.png');


 finalbg = loadImage('escenario-final.png');
 superFinal = loadImage('Superpapa-final.png');
 letrasFinal = loadImage('letras-final.png');
 pulsaAqui = loadImage('pulsa-aqui.png');
 logoFinal = loadImage('logo-final.png');
 superPapaLetras = loadImage('super-letras.png');
 pipe_img = loadImage('obs.png');
}

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you download local server like live-server or browser-sync (they are all javascript lightweight servers)
2. Start your srever from the root of the project.
3. Suppose this is your file structure:

   - Project.

     - index.html
     - app.js (where your setup goes)
     - images (super.png,fondo_juego.png)

4 . Your preload should look like this:`function preload() { img = loadImage('./images/super.png'); bg = loadImage('./images/fondo_juego.png');`

5 . with your server ,serving from the root folder this will defintely work.